# Using Google Maps API v2 on devices without Google Play

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

Google Maps API V2 for Android is a big leap forward compared to v1: better rendering, fragment support... But there is one grey area I am trying to clarify about its use.

I look forward to create a map-based application for an Android device **that does not have Google Play on it** i.e. did not pass Google validation such as a low-end tablet or a car radio, and distrbute it on third-party markets.
Such applications using V1 API are possible.

The V2 has a dependency on Google Play Services, which is available to devices with Google Play only.
Does it mean that the V2 API is definitely unavailable for the aforementioned devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I look forward to create a map-based application for an Android device that does not have Google Play on it i.e. did not pass Google validation such as a low-end tablet or a car radio, and distrbute it on third-party markets. Such applications using V1 API are possible.

Only because the makers of those devices pirated the Maps code, as both Maps V1 and Maps V2 are only available for manufacturers who pass validation and license that code.

> Does it mean that the V2 API is definitely unavailable for the aforementioned devices?

Barring similar piracy, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try manually install the bin files that are required for Google maps, same way as you would do if you wanted to get the emulator running a Google Map API V2.

you can get more information on how it's done from the following blog post I wrote:

[link](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=527)

I don't know if this solution will be applicable for those devices but you can try it.

Comment: Please do not advocate software piracy on StackOverflow.