# how to make app that uses play service to work without it?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I have developed an android app that uses play services for maps.
is it possible to made part of app that doesn't need to play services works without it?

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps Android API is part of the Google Play services platform. So if you want to use it, you need to set up the Google Play services SDK in your app development project

Also as you can see in the [Attribution Requirements](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intro#attribution_requirements) it states that:

> If you use the Google Maps Android API in your application, you must
>   include the Google Play Services attribution text as part of a "Legal
>   Notices" section in your application. Including legal notices as an
>   independent menu item, or as part of an "About" menu item, is
>   recommended.

By checking other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910266/how-to-show-maps-in-an-android-app-if-google-play-services-is-not-installed-on), I find here that, If the Google Play Services application is not installed on your user's device, you may fall back to other providers like [Google Static Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#quick_example)

You can also check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473927/using-google-maps-api-v2-on-devices-without-google-play) for more information.

Comment: no I mean I don't want to show maps , so users can use other part of the application

Comment: Then if you are not using maps, then I think it is possible, but if you need to use another API of Google you need to use Google Play services. Google Play Services is a library for your project. It is not specific to an activity, whether you use it or not it all depends on you.

Answer (score 0):

No, since google maps is part of  [Google Play Services](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en). The only thing you can do is side load google play services on the device or if the device has access to the play store you  [start an intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) that takes them to where they can install it. If the Google Play Services application is `not installed` on your user's device, you may fall back to other providers. **You need google play services to show  [map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/)**.

Comment: no I mean I don't want to show maps , so users can use other part of the application